Visual Studio Code does not allow me to use the image when I place it as a background for a tag in html
When I use one of my stock images to put it as an html background, Visual Studio Code doesn't allow it, it doesn't consider it to exist.
Although I resized the image and wrote its full path, the problem still persists
.main {
  width                 : 100%;
  min-height            : 100vh;
  display               : flex;
  align-items           : center;
  background            : url(images/background.jpeg) no-repeat;
  background-size       : cover;
  background-position   : center;
  background-attachment : fixed;
  }


Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.

You should use to use relative url.
If your images folder is in the same folder as your css file, you can use this relative path: ./images/background.jpeg
If your images folder is not in the same folder as your css file
like this
your-project-folder
|-images
  |- background.jpeg
|-css-files
  |- styles.css

You should use ../images/background.jpeg
Try out below code:
.main {
  width                 : 100%;
  min-height            : 100vh;
  display               : flex;
  align-items           : center;
  background            : url("./images/background.jpeg") no-repeat;
  background-size       : cover;
  background-position   : center;
  background-attachment : fixed;
  }


First, check you are indeed typing in the correct path. You could be missing something.
Then, try using another path. Use a path relative to your root folder using a slash /, for example:
url('/folder/yourfile.jpeg')
Or use a path relative to your file using a dot and slash ./ (or multiple)

Example 1:
url('./folder/yourfile.jpeg')

Example 2: url('../folder/folder/yourfile.jpeg')


I also like using quotation marks in my url() functions :)
